# Is it possible to read whole XML file without nested loops

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm new with XML and I would like do get help with a task. I need to write a parser for XML file (see below). The parser should return `HashTable<String, List<String>>` where key is action name and the list contains argument names in the same order as those names appear in XML file. The most important here is ORDER of arguments names.
The XML:

```
....
<actions>
    <action>
            <name>ActionName1</name>
            <arguments>
                <argument>
                    <name>name1</name>
                    <type>type1</type>
                    <comment>comment</comment>
                </argument>
                 <argument>
                      <name>name2</name>
                      <type>type2</type>
                      <comment>comment</comment>
                 </argument>
                   <argument>
                       <name>name3</name>
                       <type>type3</type>
                       <comment>comment</comment>
                   </argument>
            </arguments>
        </action>
        <action>
            <name>ActionName2</name>
            <arguments>
                  ...
            </arguments>
        </action>   
 </actions>
```

The code:

```
 ...   
    String expression = "//actions/action";
    XPathExpression compiled = xPath.compile(expression);
    nodeList = (NodeList) compiled.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                 
         Node node = nodeList.item(i);
         NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
                 
         for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
              Node child = children.item(j);
              
              if (child.getNodeName().equals("name")) {
                //add new entry to map, meanwhile just print it
                 System.out.println(child.getTextContent());
                 continue;
              }
              
              if (child.getNodeName().equals("arguments")) {
                Element element = (Element) child;
                NodeList names = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
                for (int k = 0; k < names.getLength() ; k++) {
                     Node nameNode = names.item(k);
                     //add element to list, meanwhile print it
                     System.out.println("\t" + nameNode.getTextContent());
                }
         }            
    }
```

The code works, but it is so bulky and has 2 nested loops.
Is there any more effective and simple way to implement needed functionality?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider moving to XPath 3.1 with Saxon 10 HE (or Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE) and then your XPath would be simply

```
map:merge(//action!map { name : arguments/argument/name/string() })
```

or

```
map:merge(//action!map { name : array { arguments/argument/name/string() }})
```

and then using s9api it should be able to get from the XPath 3.1 XDM map to your Java HashTable or to simply use the XDM map:

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(true);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

    XdmNode input = docBuilder.build(new File("sample-actions1.xml"));

    XPathCompiler xpathCompiler = processor.newXPathCompiler();

    xpathCompiler.declareNamespace("map", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map");

    XdmMap result = (XdmMap)xpathCompiler.evaluateSingle("map:merge(//action!map { string(name) : arguments/argument/name/string() })", input);

    System.out.println(result);
```